# Javascript missing ) after arguments list

Tags: javascript, console

A JavaScript function that takes a string argument and counts its properties.
I'm not sure why it's not working I think there is some problem with the console.log line.

```
function superCounter (TheWord) {

  var NOWords = TheWord.split('').length;
  var NOLetters = TheWord.length;
  var NOSpaces = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < superCounter.length; i++)
    if (TheWord[i] === " ") {
      NOSpaces = +1;
    }

  var CTCharacters = TheWord.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, "");
  var TNCharacters = CTCharacters.length;
  var AWLength = NOLetters / NOWords;

  console.log("words:"
    NOWords, "letters:"
    NOLetters, "spaces:"
    NOSpaces, "chars:"
    TNCharacters, "avgLength:"
    AWLength)
}
superCounter("The grintch made it happen");
```

Comment: You need commas between *every* argument when calling a function - including arguments separated by newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log` statement is wrong this is the write one.

You have missed commas after every argument. `console.log` arguments should be separated by `,`.

```
// console.log("words:" NOWords, "letters:" NOLetters, "spaces:" NOSpaces, "chars:" TNCharacters, "avgLength:" AWLength)

console.log("words:", NOWords, "letters:", NOSpaces, "chars:", TNCharacters, "avgLength:", AWLength);
```

Comment: The lack of semicolon in the original code isn't actually a syntax error.

Comment: @nnnnnn, Thanks, I ll change it